# Ajax Copy To Clipboard Not Working (Clipboard.js + Jquery)

Tags: jquery, ajax, clipboard

I have a button. Said button needs to contact the server for a unique URL and put that URL on the user's clipboard. I've tried a bunch of different approaches, but none seem to work. At the moment I'm trying this:

```js
var clipboardItems = new Clipboard('.action_share_file', {
 text: function (trigger) {
  var result = '';
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   async: false,
   url: '/files/change/permissions/' + $('#contextMenu-item').attr('data-id'),
   data: 'permissions=' + JSON.stringify({'read' : 'link'}),
   dataType: "json",
   success: function (msg) {
    //result = msg.url;
                // for testing purposes.
                result = 'yay';
   }
  });

  return result;
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/1.5.16/clipboard.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="action_share_file">Get Share URL</button>
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work even though it's synchronous. I'll take any suggestion that allows me to request the URL and put it on the user's clipboard in one go.

Comment: I recreated your example [in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ToJa92/0jwnycwk/) and it seems to be working well. So perhaps the issue lies elsewhere. Is there anything printed in the console at all when you press the button (in your version, that is)?

Comment: Here's what my code looks like exactly: http://nerd.guru/screenshots/chrome_2017-01-02_23-46-34.png Here's the console output: http://nerd.guru/screenshots/chrome_2017-01-02_23-45-26.png The json is valid (but I'm not using it I'm trying to copy 'yay' at the moment). I'm starting to think the only reason this is failing is because the browser may have some weird maximum time to do action after click that I'm passing?